# Can a walk be equivalently viewed as a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path says

> - A walk is a finite or infinite sequence of edges which joins a sequence of vertices. Let G = (V, E, ϕ) be a graph. A finite walk is a
>   sequence of edges (e1, e2, …, en − 1) for which there is a sequence of
>   vertices (v1, v2, …, vn) such that ϕ(ei) = {vi, vi + 1} for i = 1, 2,
>   …, n − 1. (v1, v2, …, vn) is the vertex sequence of the walk. This
>   walk is closed if v1 = vn, and open else. An infinite walk is a
>   sequence of edges of the same type described here, but with no first
>   or last vertex, and a semi-infinite walk (or ray) has a first vertex
>   but no last vertex.
> - A trail is a walk in which all edges are distinct.
> - A path is a trail in which all vertices (and therefore also all edges) are distinct.

Is it correct that

- A walk is by definition a sequence of edges, so a walk is not a graph?
- A path, which is defined as a special walk, is not a graph by definition? A lot of graph theory books say that a path is a graph. Are these two different meanings of a path equivalent?
- Can a walk be equivalently viewed as a graph? ("equivalently" means without loss of information. Since a walk may repeat an edge, while a graph's edge set doesn't contain an edge more than once, I doubt a walk can be equivalently viewed as a graph)
- Can a trail be equivalently viewed as a graph? (I guess so, because a trail is defined to not have repeated edges, which makes it equivalent to a graph)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The two notions of a path are as follows:

- A "path graph": a graph isomorphic to one with $n$ vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and $n-1$ edges $v_1 v_2, v_2 v_3, \dots, v_{n-1} v_n$. Commonly denoted $P_n$.
- A path inside a graph $G$. Sometimes this is defined as a type of walk, as you did; less commonly, this is defined as a subgraph of $G$ isomorphic to $P_n$ (for some $n$).

---

The most careful way to define a walk is a sequence of vertices *and* edges: $v_0, e_1, v_1, e_2, v_2, \dots, e_n, v_n$, where each edge $e_i$ joins $v_{i-1}$ to $v_i$. But of course just the sequence of edges is enough to infer the vertices. In a *simple* graph, the sequence of vertices is also enough to infer the edges, so we could use either definition.

For any walk in a graph $G$, we could instead consider the subgraph of $G$ consisting of all the edges included in the walk. But we always lose some information by doing this.

- In the case of a walk, as you've noticed, we lose the most information. An edge could be part of the walk multiple times, and the subgraph idea forgets all about that.
- Even for a trail, we forget some information by passing to the subgraph. Suppose we have a complete graph on vertices $1,2,3,4,5$. The closed trail that goes $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 1 \to 4 \to 5 \to 1$ is different in many ways from the trail that goes $5 \to 4 \to 1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 1 \to 5$, but they have the same edge set. Or, take any Eulerian graph: there could be many different Eulerian trails, but they would all give the same subgraph, which is the whole graph.
- We lose almost no information for a path, but we still lose one thing: orientation. We might want to distinguish the paths $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 4 \to 5$ and $5 \to 4 \to 3 \to 2 \to 1$, but they definitely give the same subgraph.

Sometimes, though, we *want* to lose the information, and consider the subgraph instead of the sequence. This is especially common for cycles: closed walks in which no vertex is repeated except for the first and the last vertex being the same. If we take an $n$-vertex cycle, there are $2n$ closed walks total with that set of edges: we can start at any of $n$ vertices, and go in either of $2$ directions. But we don't really think of those as different cycles.

Comment: Thanks. Does your reply only assume undirected graph? What about walk, trail, and path in a  directed graph?

Comment: In a directed graph, a path is indistinguishable from its edge set, because the edges give an orientation. But there are still different trails and walks with the same edge set, for mostly the same reasons.